# How should i link users with fixed questions and answers in symfony2 doctrine2 classes

Tags: php, symfony, linker, doctrine-orm

I have these classes

```
class Questioncategory {
    one to many
    private $questions
}
```

```php
class Questions{
   many to one
   private $category

   one to many
   private $answers
}
```

```php
class answers {
    many to one
    private questions
}
```

The scenario is that when I register the user then there are predefined set of questions  like feedback form on the web page which user has to fill. The questions will have different categories like `personal questions`, `technical questions` etc

1. Now these questions are fixed but these questions are different for different age groups.
2. Although the questions are will be same for same age group but I think I need to first grab the questions from database based on user agegroup and then link it to user table
   or is there any other way?

Now my problems:

**How to show link in user table?** I mean

```
class user{
    private questions or answers or category
}
```

I am confused first

**How to show the questions category wise on the page like**

```
personal questions

1What is you age  <input text box>
2What is your eye color <input text box
and other catregories
```

I mean how should i iterate through doctrine `$user->question->getcategory->getQuestions`

and then how to bind the form with answers table

Comment: You should probably start here: [Doctrine 2 ORM's _Getting Started_ documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html)

Comment: can you please tell if i should put categories in usertable and access like `user-categories-questions` or put questions there `user-questions`

Answer (score 0):

- create AgeGroup entity
- add relation User has one AgeGroup
- add relation Questioncategory belong to one AgeGroup
- to get list of user questions: user->AgeGroup->Category->Questions to get possible answers
- add relation user->answers to get answers selected by user